# add a default git source to visual studio?

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio, bitbucket

I use bitbucket and I clone repos via VS.

I have to manually paste in the https repo link in vs in order to clone it (in the team explorer tab).

Is there a way I could point VS to bitbucket so I can browse my bitbucket repos and choose the one I want instead of having to manually find the link and paste it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Visual Studio page "Clone an existing Git repo"](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/clone) is quite clear:

> Before you can clone an existing repo, you'll need a URL that points to the existing repo. This URL represents the source of the repo you're going to copy during the clone.

So you need to copy it beforehand: you cannot "browse" the available repos directly from VS.

For instance:

> If you need to clone a GitHub repo, you'll need to get the clone URL from the Clone or download button while viewing the repo on the web in GitHub.
>
> Other Git providers have similar buttons in their user interface to get the clone URL.

For Visual Studio, you can then check out "[Visual Studio Bitbucket Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MistyK.VisualStudioBitbucketExtension)".
It includes the feature:

> Clone - lists all existing Bitbucket repositories and allows user to clone it locally.

Comment: Is there maybe a community VS plugin that could do this for me??